# Bad Request, Header too long With Error Code 400 (Run using IIS Server .netCore Application)

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

After the completion of about 40-45 APIs, the size of the authorization token is around 40 kb. And now after login whenever any request is being sent to the server it gives an error of "Bad Request, Header too long.

[image]

For Kestrel Server the blow code has been solved the error -

```
webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
options.Limits.MaxRequestHeadersTotalSize = 1048576;
})
```

But for IIS Server I haven't got any kind of solution
The solution I have tried is

1. Increased the RequestLimit from web.config file.
2. Add the MaxFieldLength and MaxRequestBytes in
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/System/CurrentControlSet/Services/HTTP/Parameters`
3. Add the below code in ConfigureServices method

   `services.Configure(options => { options.AutomaticAuthentication = true; options.ForwardWindowsAuthentication = true; });`

and many more tries but not got the final solution.
Please help if anyone can...

Comment: maybe this can help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded/3853785#3853785

Comment: Tried all the codes related to web.config attached in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded/3853785#3853785

Not worked

Comment: You mean you have an `aud` claim with a list of 40+ audience URLs ? In any case, you should REALLY reconsider what you are doing. Such token should not exist.

Comment: Any success solving this issue on IIS? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this link here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/el-GR/troubleshoot/iis/httpsys-registry-windows

There are some registry settings, that limit IIS maxLenght. Depending on your IIS version, this could vary.
They keys you should look for probably are:

MaxFieldLength (per header size)
MaxRequestBytes (total size of request)